# Swift 3.0 NumberFormatter strange behavior Simulator vs Real device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I have an issue with converting string to double on swift 3.0 and ios 10.2

for example I have string `"1.25098"` and converting it to double `"1.25098".strToDouble()` using extension for String

```
extension String {
  func strToDouble() -> Double? {
     return NumberFormatter().number(from: self)?.doubleValue
  }
}
```

Result of that (both iOS 10.2):

- Simulator: 1.25098
- Real device: nil

**UPDATE**
:Fixed with setting decimalSeparator

```
    extension String {
      func strToDouble() -> Double? {
       let formator = NumberFormatter()
       formator.decimalSeparator = "."
       return formator.number(from: self)?.doubleValue
      }
    }
```

Comment: Different locale with different decimal separator for example?

Comment: oh my god you're right. Thank you @vadian !